# Event booking application with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have set up an event booking application with ruby on rails where I have users who can create events and the general public can book events. I am having problems implementing the booking feature. This is what I have done so far.

Created a Booking resource and associated it with the event model. The booking model contains the following attributes

- Booker name
- Booker Email
- event_id

The goal is to "create a booking" for a current event. However I do not know how to pass the "current_event" parameter to the booking controller and I am also not sure how to define a "current_event".

Comment: Why did you put user details inside the Booking model? why not just make it have two columns: `user_id` and `event_id`?

Comment: "My problem is how to create a link with every event such that it selects the current events_id as the booking event_id." This is not understandable, please clarify what you are trying to do. Do you mean that you are trying to get all bookings of a specific `event_id`?

Comment: The user details in the booking model is not for event_creators rather its for the public trying to book an event. Sorry is my question is unclear. I have edited it.

Comment: You'll either need [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) or you'll have to use a [`nested resource`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) on the event resource. If you give more information, we'll be in a better position to put forward answers for you

Comment: "associated it with the user model" I think you mean that you've associated it with the Event model, right?

Comment: Yes I meant "event model", I will edit that.

Comment: Thanks Rich, I really wanted to avoid nesting as I always get confused. I will try it though this time around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your routes file like this (rails 4):

```
EventManagement::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :events do
    resources :bookings
  end
end
```

This will give you a "nested route" -- the route to bookings is always "nested" under events.  To create a new booking for an event, you'll use the new_event_booking_path(@event) route and to view a list of all the bookings for the event it's just event_bookings_path(@event).  Each of these routes will put the event_id into the params hash.

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_event

  def index
    @bookings = @event.bookings
  end

  def new
    @booking = @event.bookings.build
  end

  def create
    @booking = @event.bookings.build booking_params
    if @booking.save
      ..
    else
      ...
    end
  end

  private
    def load_event
      @event = Event.find params[:event_id]
    end

    def bookings_params
      params.require(:bookings).permit(:booker_name, :booker_email)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually I don't think you should have a Booking resource, but rather an Event resource and only a Booking model. The *booking* should happen in the `events_controller`, where you can easily specify the current `@event`.

Were I you, I would do the following.

```
# app/models/event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
end

# /models/booking.rb
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end

# app/controllers/events_controller.rb
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  # POST /events/{:id}/book
  def book_new_ticket
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    if @event.bookings.where(email: params[:email]).count > 0
      redirect_to '/somewhere', alert: "THIS EMAIL HAS ALREADY BOOKED, YOU FOOL!"
    else
      Booking.create!(name: params[:name], email: params[:email], event_id: @event.id)
    end
  end

end
```

Haven't really run this code, but it's just a simulation.

Comment: You said only a booking model however your book_new_ticket method is in a booking controller. is that supposed to be in the event controller ?

Comment: As a not with Joshua you mark the controller section of your sample as `events_controller.rb` but the class you define is `BookingController`. I assume you meant `EventsController` but wanted to bring that to your attention.

Comment: @Joshua @izuriel Yes you're right, I meant it to be an `EventsController` as the comment above of it tells, I'll edit it now, sorry for the typo.

Comment: Thanks Tamer, I was trying to figure out why my solution to the booking problem wasn't working and @andyV is closer to what I tried to do.